# Issue to align vertically content of 3 divs

Tags: html, css

I'd like to align the content of 3 divs (type, desc, lang) vertically. I tried vertical-align:middle but without success. If you look at this link http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/Twru8/ you will notice that the pictures seems to be aligned to the top of the div. What is the issue? Thanks

CSS

```
.medias-table-content-type, .medias-table-content-desc, .medias-table-content-lang {
    padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #000;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vertical-align` (note: case sensitive) is applicable only to these elements:

```
COL, CUSTOM, IMG, SPAN, TBODY, TD, TFOOT, TH, THEAD, TR
```

So `vertical-align` style is not applicable for `DIV` unless you change its display to `table-cell` (i.e.: `TD` element) by adding `display:table-cell;` to its CSS. `float` style must not be used also, since it'll force an element to be displayed as `inline-block`.

So the relevant CSS should be like this:

```
.medias-table-content-type, .medias-table-content-desc, .medias-table-content-lang {
    padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #000;
    width: 50px;
    /*deleted
    float: left;
    */
    position: relative;
    /*added*/
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center content inside the box. Give a `line-height` value the same as the height of the box. So in your example, the box is 60px, then make `line-height` of the box also 60px. But you need to remove all other padding and margin for the image.